# Spark df.cache() is causing org.apache.spark.memory.SparkOutOfMemoryError

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm having this issue where everything works fine but when I use `df.cache()` it causes `org.apache.spark.memory.SparkOutOfMemoryError` issue.

Has anyone ever had similiar issue?

Thank you!

Here's the lines of code that caused the issue:

```py
df.cache()
df = df.select(
    *df.columns,
    f.greatest(*custom_columns).alias(f"custom_max"),
    f.least(*custom_columns).alias(f"custom_min"),
)
return df
```

And here's the error log:

```
[2021-04-17 08:54:35,894] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 19: Subtask compute_outcomes [Stage 2:=======================================>               (144 + 4) / 200]
[2021-04-17 08:54:54,481] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 19: Subtask compute_outcomes [Stage 2:========================================>              (148 + 4) / 200]2021-04-17 08:54:54 WARN  MemoryStore:66 - Failed to reserve initial memory threshold of 1024.0 KB for computing block rdd_173_11 in memory.
[2021-04-17 08:54:54,494] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 19: Subtask compute_outcomes 2021-04-17 08:54:54 WARN  MemoryStore:66 - Not enough space to cache rdd_173_11 in memory! (computed 384.0 B so far)
[2021-04-17 08:54:54,495] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 19: Subtask compute_outcomes 2021-04-17 08:54:54 WARN  MemoryStore:66 - Failed to reserve initial memory threshold of 1024.0 KB for computing block rdd_173_17 in memory.
[2021-04-17 08:54:54,496] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 19: Subtask compute_outcomes 2021-04-17 08:54:54 WARN  MemoryStore:66 - Not enough space to cache rdd_173_17 in memory! (computed 384.0 B so far)
[2021-04-17 08:54:54,505] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 19: Subtask compute_outcomes 2021-04-17 08:54:54 WARN  BlockManager:66 - Persisting block rdd_173_11 to disk instead.
====
There are a bunch of WARN like this in between
====
[2021-04-17 08:55:13,178] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 19: Subtask compute_outcomes 2021-04-17 08:55:13 WARN  MemoryStore:66 - Not enough space to cache rdd_285_0 in memory! (computed 384.0 B so far)
[2021-04-17 08:55:13,242] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 19: Subtask compute_outcomes 2021-04-17 08:55:13 ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 4.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 154)
[2021-04-17 08:55:13,242] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 19: Subtask compute_outcomes org.apache.spark.memory.SparkOutOfMemoryError: Unable to acquire 65536 bytes of memory, got 0
[2021-04-17 08:55:13,242] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 19: Subtask compute_outcomes     at org.apache.spark.memory.MemoryConsumer.throwOom(MemoryConsumer.java:157)
[2021-04-17 08:55:13,242] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 19: Subtask compute_outcomes     at org.apache.spark.memory.MemoryConsumer.allocateArray(MemoryConsumer.java:98)
[2021-04-17 08:55:13,242] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 19: Subtask compute_outcomes     at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeInMemorySorter.<init>(UnsafeInMemorySorter.java:128)
[2021-04-17 08:55:13,242] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 19: Subtask compute_outcomes     at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter.<init>(UnsafeExternalSorter.java:161)
[2021-04-17 08:55:13,242] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 19: Subtask compute_outcomes     at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter.create(UnsafeExternalSorter.java:128)
[2021-04-17 08:55:13,243] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 19: Subtask compute_outcomes     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.<init>(UnsafeExternalRowSorter.java:108)
[2021-04-17 08:55:13,243] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 19: Subtask compute_outcomes     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.create(UnsafeExternalRowSorter.java:93)
[2021-04-17 08:55:13,243] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 19: Subtask compute_outcomes     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SortExec.createSorter(SortExec.scala:87)
[2021-04-17 08:55:13,243] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 19: Subtask compute_outcomes     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SortExec$$anonfun$1.apply(SortExec.scala:102)
[2021-04-17 08:55:13,243] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 19: Subtask compute_outcomes     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SortExec$$anonfun$1.apply(SortExec.scala:101)
[2021-04-17 08:55:13,243] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 19: Subtask compute_outcomes     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:836)
[2021-04-17 08:55:13,243] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 19: Subtask compute_outcomes     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:836)
[2021-04-17 08:55:13,243] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 19: Subtask compute_outcomes     at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
[2021-04-17 08:55:13,243] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 19: Subtask compute_outcomes     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
[2021-04-17 08:55:13,243] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 19: Subtask compute_outcomes     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
[2021-04-17 08:55:13,244] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 19: Subtask compute_outcomes     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
[2021-04-17 08:55:13,244] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 19: Subtask compute_outcomes     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
[2021-04-17 08:55:13,244] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 19: Subtask compute_outcomes     at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
[2021-04-17 08:55:13,244] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 19: Subtask compute_outcomes     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[2021-04-17 08:55:13,244] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 19: Subtask compute_outcomes     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[2021-04-17 08:55:13,244] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 19: Subtask compute_outcomes     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

`df.cache` will cache your entire dataframe into executor's memories. So this error means your executors don't have sufficient memory. You will need to give it more using `--executor-memory`